# QuickBooks Enterprise Desktop Integration with Java

Tags: java, sdk, integration, desktop, quickbooks

I am facing issue related to connecting with Quickbooks Desktop version(Intuit QuickBooks Enterprise Solutions 14.0) using Quickbooks SDK.

I need to develop a java application to post the data of Invoices in Quickbooks Desktop version. I have installed Quickbooks SDK (https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0250_ … _downloads) but not able to connect with SDK using java program.

Please let me know how to get the available libraries for java and QBFC com. Also the document for those library.

We are using QBFC and not able to find QBFC library in the SDK which can be used in the java code but we found QBFC installer. How can it be used.
We have also written a code to call the methods that are available in SDK. Initially, we are trying to call authenticate method. The code is as following :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException, MalformedURLException {
      qbConnector m = new qbConnector();
      com.intuit.developer.QBWebConnectorSvcSoap a = m.callQB();
      try {
          System.out.println(a);
        a.authenticate("qbadmin","123456");
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
public com.intuit.developer.QBWebConnectorSvcSoap callQB() throws ServiceException, MalformedURLException{

      URL url = new URL("https://sandbox-qbsoapserver.cs21.force.com/services/Soap/class/QBSoapServer");

      return getQBWebConnectorSvcSoap(url);
  }
```

We are getting the following error :

```
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intuit.developer.qbConnector.main(qbConnector.java:42)
Line 42 in the code -  a.authenticate("qbadmin","123456")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get the solution? I have same problem. Please guide

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into using QODBC to interface with Quickbooks. It allows you to treat QB's XML data like database tables. I used it with VB and it was *so* much easier than trying to figure out the QBs documentation. One caveat, however, you may have to have an instance of QBs running in order to connect to it.
[Java & QODBC](http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/383/76/how-can-qodbc-driver-work-with-the-java-odbc-bridge-product)